# I have got error in my simple kotlin calculator

Tags: kotlin, input, syntax-error, readline, calculation

When I run this code, I have a problem. I want to build a simple calculator, so I need to use readLine() but I face error in subtraction, multiplication and division operations. This is the code, Please help me.

```
fun main()
{
print("1. Addition\n2. Subtraction\n3. Multiplication\n4. Division\nChoose Number: ")

var choosen = readLine()

print("Enter The First Number: ")

var num1 = readLine()

print("Enter The Second Number: ")

var num2 = readLine()

if (choosen?.toInt() == 1){

    print("The Result Is: ${num1 + num2}")

} else if (choosen?.toInt() == 2){

    print("The Result Is: ${num1 - num2}")

} else if (choosen?.toInt() == 3){

    print("The Result Is: ${num1 * num2}")

} else if (choosen?.toInt() == 4){

    print("The Result Is: ${num1 / num2}")

} else {

    print("Wrong Input")

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that -, *, and / are not compiling is, that *num1* and *num2* are strings. + will work, but it will not add *num1* and *num2*, it will concatenate the two values.

I would suggest to use *readln()* instead of *readLine()*, because you are guaranteed to get a *String*. *readLine()* returns an optional *String?*.

The input can immediately be converted to *Int* with *toIntOrNull()*. So if something is entered that can not be converted to an *Int* we will have *null* for *num1* and/or *num2*.

The next step is to test if the input is valid, hence the *if* clause.

Only if the input is valid, it makes sense to apply the operator to the two operands. And the *when* statement is more elegant than multiple *if* *else if* statements.

```
print("1. Addition\n2. Subtraction\n3. Multiplication\n4. Division\nChoose Number: ")
val chosen = readln()
print("Enter The First Number: ")
val num1 = readln().toIntOrNull()
print("Enter The Second Number: ")
val num2 = readln().toIntOrNull()

if (chosen !in listOf("1", "2", "3", "4") || num1 == null || num2 == null) {
  print("Invalid input")
} else {
  val result = when (chosen) {
    "1"  -> num1 + num2
    "2"  -> num1 - num2
    "3"  -> num1 * num2
    "4"  -> num1 / num2
    else -> null   // will never happen, see 'if' clause
  }
  print("The result is: $result")
}
```